# When you create an instance of a subclass an instance of its superclass is also created, is it possible to access it?

Tags: python, inheritance

I was learning about inheritance in python and it is made very clear in python that once you create an instance of a subclass and instance of the corresponding superclass is also created

```
class Dog():
    def __init__(self,breed,age,hasowner):
        print('Dog created')
        self.breed = breed
        self.age = age; 
        self.hasowner = hasowner; 


    specie = 'mammal'

class Beagle(Dog):

    def __init__(self):
        Dog.__init__(self,'beagle',5,True)
        print('beagle created')
my_beagle = Beagle()
```

as expected when the following piece of code is executed "Dog created" and "Beagle created" are both printed on the console.

So I was wondering how could I access this Dog object that is created?

Comment: `my_beagle` *is* now also a `Dog`object... `my_beagle.breed` will exist and be initialized. and `super().__init__('beagle', 5, True)` is the pythonic way to call the initalizer of the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how it works. An instance of Dog is not "also" created. There is *one* instance, that is *both* Dog and Beagle; because a Beagle "is-a" Dog.

The point of inheritance is that any attribute defined on Dog is also available on Beagle (unless you override it).

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that you can use `super()` to access attributes of the parent class that *have* been overridden in a child class.

Comment: I was also wondering: in my code all the instances of Beagle would share the same value for the attributes breed age and hasowner right? So this would mimic the behavior of  class object attributes to some extent?

Comment: No `breed`, `age` and `hasowner` are instance attributes so they aren’t shared - they are accessed using e,g, `self.breed`. `specie` is a class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

That is not what happens.

A single instance is created, that is at the same time a `Beagle` and a `Dog`. The call to the method in the `Dog` class inside `Beagle.__init__`  just runs the code in Dog as well - A subclass, also being an instance of the superclass, have to provide for the code on the ancestors to be run. (That is more usually done through the use of `super()` than hardcoding the superclass name, though).

Moreover, in statically typed languages, usually you can "cast" a subclass to one of its superclasses - so that you can create  a "Beagle", cast it to "Dog", and call directly "Dog" methods on the resulting object - that is not the case in Python - it is not ordinarily possible to 'cast' an object to its superclass. rahter, any call that would accept an object of the type of the superclass will also take in objects objects of any of its subclasses.

The `super(...)` call can be used to explicitly invoke methods or attributes of the superclasses from outside the class methods as well - so, if you declare the classes as:

```py
class Dog():
    def __init__(self,breed,age,hasowner):
        print('Dog created')
        self.breed = breed
        self.age = age
        self.hasowner = hasowner

    def bark(self):
        print('dog bark')


    specie = 'mammal'

class Beagle(Dog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('beagle',5,True)
        print('beagle created')

    def bark(self):
        print('beagle bark')

my_beagle = Beagle()
```

You can do this (output from the interactive console, after pasting the snippet above):

```
In [147]: my_beagle.bark()                                                                                                                             
beagle bark

In [148]: super(Beagle, my_beagle).bark()                                                                                                              
dog bark
```

So you can use Dog's methods, but it is not a separate instance! 
(Also note that when used out of a subclass method body, `super()` requires the class and instance parameters to be given explicitly)